# VB LINQ datatable - latest dates in the ascending order

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following table and data:

```
Date  |Symbol|Return
Jan 1 |   A  |  1%
Jan 2 |   A  |  2%
Jan 3 |   A  |  4%
Jan 5 |   A  |  0%
Jan 6 |   A  | -1%
Jan 7 |   A  | -3%
Jan 8 |   A  |  5%
```

The table is already sorted in ascending order. What I'm trying to accomplish is to query for the **last/latest** 3 records and sort them in **ascending** order by date:

```
Date  |Symbol|Return
Jan 6 |   A  | -1%
Jan 7 |   A  | -3%
Jan 8 |   A  |  5%
```

Here's my code:

```
Dim ReturnArray = (From row In DT_Symbols.AsEnumerable()
    Where row.Field(Of String)("Symbol") = Symbol.Key 'Dictionary Key
    Take 3
    Select row.Field(Of Double)("Return")).Distinct()
```

The problem with the above is that when I `Order By row.Field(Of Date)("Date") Ascending` I'm getting Jan1, Jan2, & Jan3 dates and that's not what I want.

When I Order By `row.Field(Of Date)("Date") Descending` - I get correct dates (Jan 6, 7, & 8) **BUT** in wrong order (Jan 8,7,6).

Can you please suggest a workaround?

Thank you!

Comment: How about taking first three in Descending order, and then `Reverse()` them?

Comment: Thanks Andrei Reverse() did the trick. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Consider revising your code to:

```
Dim ReturnArray =
    (From row In DT_Symbols
    Where row.Field(Of String)("Symbol") = Symbol.Key 'Dictionary Key
    Take 3
    Select row.Field(Of Double)("Return")).Distinct().ToList().Reverse()
```

You shouldn't need to call `AsEnumerable()` at the beginning. At the end, we call `ToList()` to execute the query and return the 3 distinct results, then use `Reverse()` to order them descending (as Andrei suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Use Skip.

```
Dim ReturnArray = (From row In DT_Symbols
Where row.Field(Of String)("Symbol") = Symbol.Key 'Dictionary Key
OrderBy Date
Skip DT_Symbols.Count - 3
Take 3
Select row.Field(Of Double)("Return")).Distinct()
```